# Error: a struct with a similar name exists - Rust

Tags: rust

Estoy comenzando con Rust y estoy intentando programar una lista con punteros puros.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
struct Lista<T>{
    root: *mut NodoLista<T>,
    nodos: u32,
}

pub struct NodoLista<T>{
    pub value: T,
    pub child: *mut NodeLista<T>,
}

impl<T> NodoLista<T>{
    
    fn new(value:T)->NodoLista<T>{
        NodoLista::<T>{value, child:None}
    }

}

impl<T> Lista<T>{

    fn new(){
        Lista::<T>{root:None, nodos: 0};
    }

    fn len(self)->u32{
        return self.nodos;
    }
        
}

fn main(){

    let lista = Lista::new();

    println!("Tamaño de la lista {}", lista.len());

}
```

Al compilar me devuelve el siguiente error:

`error[E0412]: cannot find type 'NodeLista' in this scope`

`help: a struct with a similar name exists: 'NodoLista'`

Como podria resolver ese problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiando `NodeLista` a `NodoLista`, el compilador te esta diciendo que `NodeLista` NO EXISTE y te sugiere que uses el nombre de la estructura que ya definiste `NodoLista`
Estas usando `NodeLista` como tipo del segundo campo de la misma estructura.
También te recomiendo usar `Option<Box<_>>` no tienes que usar tanto `unsafe` y el compilador lo optimizara a un puntero(incluso [std::mem::size_of](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) te dirá que su tamaño es el mismo que el de un puntero puro)

Si insistes con los punteros entonces tal vez te interesaría [NonNull](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html).